# How to change the default action of the index controller zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have just created a new Zend project. I want to use the `setDefaultAction` to change the default action of the Index controller to any other action of the Index controller. I know that I need to code something like :

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setDefaultAction("about");
```

but in what function I need to code this? Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 7):

You could do this in your config

```
; application.ini
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "about"
```

Mind you, this will set the default action for all controllers.

An alternative option would be to set a static route for the home page (/), eg

```
; application.ini
resources.router.routes.home.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
resources.router.routes.home.route = "/"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.action = "about"
```

Comment: Note: don't copy and paste the "# application.ini" as it will break your config file.

Comment: @JonnyWhite right you are, should have been `;`. Fixed now