# Default home page setting in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

How many methods are there to change the default home page setting for [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework)?

I think there are the `application.ini` and `bootstrap.php` files. I am trying, but what do I do if it is not working by using these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'default home page' you mean where a request to `/` is routed, that can be changed by specifying a router other than the default.

I'm assuming you're using the 1.x ZF library, if you're on 2.x it's probably somewhat similar.

The get a better understanding of how Zend routes requests, checkout the [overview of routing in a Zend Framework application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html), specifically the end of [the section on the standard router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard) which shows what is essentially the default route. You're right that you can use the `Bootstrap.php` to programmatically define the route:

```
//get the front controller
$this->bootstrap('frontController');
$front = $this->getResource('frontController');

//custom route
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':module/:controller/:action/*',
    array('module' => 'default',
          'controller' => 'welcome',
          'action' => 'index')
);
$router->addRoute('default', $route);
$front->getRouter()->addRoute('site', $siteRoute);
```

To modify the routing from `application.ini`, follow the [documentation of that resource plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.router).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your application.ini...

```
resources.router.routes.home.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
resources.router.routes.home.route = "/"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.controller = "defaultController"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.action = "defaultAction"
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359588/369326